# Deep Neural Network using mixture of image and non image data

Tags: regression, python, deep-learning

I have rectangular bounding boxes for an object in an image, and 3-point vector of relative distances (x,y,z) of the object w.r.t camera, and 3-point vector indicating the pose of the object. I want to take the cropped patch (from bounding boxes) and resize them to 224 X 224 and pass it through to some standard networks like resnet (training from scratch) to estimate pose. Now, I think results can be improved if I use the distances and the aspect ratio (from bounding box coordinates) as input too. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a network which [merges](https://keras.io/layers/merge/) the output layer of a convolution network like ResNet (minus the top layer, if you are using pre-trained weights), and an input layer that feeds your additional inputs (the distances and aspect ratios).

You can experiment with the type of merge operation, concatenation should be a good starting point. There is a basic example of the operation, using Keras, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196636/how-to-concatenate-two-layers-in-keras).